# How Do I Subtract Variables in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I am making a text based game in batch, i need to subtract the gold of the player from the cost of the weapons/armor...can someone look at my code and tell me if they see something wrong with this?

```
@echo off 
set gold= 20

echo %gold%
pause >nul
goto blacksmith
:blacksmith
set /p weaponch=  Purchase: 

if %weaponch%==1s (
set  weaponch= 10
set a/ gold=%gold%-10
echo.
echo Gold: %gold% You have purchased the Light Sword
pause 
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your had two problems in your code.

The first was fixed by user328430s answer, where you used `a/` instead of `/a`, and also -= is easier.

The other problem is that batch fills in all the instances of `%gold%` in your if at once, as soon as it gets to it, and so it does not recognize the change until after. I suppose this is for optimization, but it leads to problems. To fix it you have to enable delayed expansion in your program, and then within the if you have to remind it to use delayed expansion for the gold variable. This is done by first using the command:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

and then switching

```
echo Gold: %gold% You have purchased the Light Sword
```

with

```
echo Gold: !gold! You have purchased the Light Sword
```

Adding that with the corrected subtraction line, you get:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set gold= 20

echo %gold%
pause >nul
goto blacksmith
:blacksmith
set /p weaponch=  Purchase 

if %weaponch%==1s ( 
set  weaponch= 10
set /a gold-=10
echo.
echo Gold: !gold! You have purchased the Light Sword
pause 
)
```

I tested that on my computer, and inputed 1s for the purchase and it worked as it should. Hope that helps.

Comment: Dude, thanks you are awesome! I've been staring at this damned thing for like an hour trying to figure out what was wrong...thanks again

Answer (score 2):

[supplemental information]

It is crucial in batch to realise that **all** variables are **strings**. No exceptions.

What may vary is the *way* the string is interpreted.

```
set gold= 20
```

sets the value of `gold` not to `20` but to **<kbd>Space</kbd>20**

set /A gold=%gold%-10

(with the `a/` corrected to `/a` - caps for emphasis (batch is largely case-insensitive)) would be executed as

set /A gold=<kbd>Space</kbd>20-10

and set **/a** evlauates this value and assigns `10` to `gold`.

Note what happens with

```
set gold= 20
if "%gold%"=="20" echo ("gold" is "20") else (echo "gold" is NOT "20")
if %gold%==20 echo (gold is 20) else (echo gold is NOT 20)
```

This kind of problem can be very hard to find, especially with trailing spaces on the line. `set /a` overcomes this for numeric assignments, and `set "var=value"` for string assignments - the only <kbd>Spaces</kbd> in the value assigned are those between the `"rabbits' ears"`

Note also that spaces on the left of the `=` can be significant - assigning to var<kbd>space</kbd> - not `var`

In short, spaces on either side of the `=` in a `set` are significant; but ignored in a `set /a`.

Similarly, `set /p` is a string assignment. There is no control over what the user types, so the value assigned may be `1` or it may be `duck soup and waffles`

Hence,

```
if %userinput%==1 goto somewhere
```

would be happy with `1` (or `2`, `3`, `99`, `hello`...) but wouldn't like `duck soup and waffles` which would be interpreted as

```
if duck soup and waffles==1 goto somewhere
```

which is clearly a syntax error.

A partial solution to this would be

```
if "%userinput%"=="1" goto somewhere
```

which would at least not crash if the input was `duck soup and waffles` but it's not bullet-proof; there are characters that may be input (those with a special meaning to the `cmd` interpreter) that could cause problems - but usually, only where the user is deliberately tryng to crash the program.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off 
set gold= 20

echo %gold%
pause >nul
goto blacksmith
:blacksmith
set /p weaponch=  Purchase: 

if %weaponch%==1s ( 
set  weaponch= 10
set /a gold-=10
echo.
echo Gold: %gold% You have purchased the Light Sword
pause 
)
```

Haven't tried the code though.

Comment: Does not work. You need to enable delayed expansion and use !gold! or else it will fill in all instances of %gold% in the if before it is ever modified. Your set /a gold -=10 part is correct though. I did not catch it either until I ran the code with the same edit and it still did not work.

Comment: Yeah, It was a quick read on your post. Perfect answer by user2403741.